# How do I identify if a path contains the last sub directory in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working with the following DataFrame:

```
    path           
0   dir_1               
1   dir_1/dir_2        
2   dir_1/dir_2/dir_3   
3   dir_1/dir_2/dir_4
```

Expected DataFrame

```
    path           is_last_dir
0   dir_1               0
1   dir_1/dir_2         0
2   dir_1/dir_2/dir_3   1
3   dir_1/dir_2/dir_4   1
```

The `path` column consists of type `str`, I would like to know how to identify if a path contains the last sub directory with reference to the other paths (i.e no directories exist after the last) without using modules like `os`.

Please Advise.

You can replicate the dataframe using the code mentioned below:

```
data_list = ['dir_1', 'dir_1/dir_2', 'dir_1/dir_2/dir_3', 'dir_1/dir_2/dir_4']


path_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns =['path'])

path_df.head()
```

Comment: what is wrong with modules like `os`?

Comment: @matszwecja The path are located on cloud.

Comment: So you only care about what is in the dataframe, not whether those paths actually exist somewhere?

Comment: Well the dataframe contains confirmed paths, and I'm trying to figure out which ones contain the last sub directories

Comment: The ones which have `is_last_dir` set to 1, I assume. 1 is True and 0 is False.

Comment: Yes @ThomasWeller

Comment: So, does that answer your question? Should I really put that as an answer? It sounds trivial, to be honest.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think they may be asking how to create that column based off of the path column.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I expect to create that column with code lol, My bad I should have made it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution compares every item in the list against every other item, so this is basically an O(n²) solution.

```py
import pandas as pd

data_list = [('dir_1', -1), ('dir_1/dir_2', -1), ('dir_1/dir_2/dir_3', -1), ('dir_1/dir_2/dir_4', -1)]

result = []
for entry in data_list:
    dir = entry[0]
    for otherentry in data_list:
        otherdir = otherentry[0]
        if otherdir.startswith(dir + "/"):
            result.append((dir, 0))
            break
    else:
        result.append((dir, 1))

path_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['path', 'is_last_dir'])
print(path_df.head())
```

Comment: There most certainly are better solutions, like creating a directory tree as you go and then checking if any given node is a leaf or no. O(n log n) vs O(n^2) I think, but it's not something I feel like implementing for an answer as well.

Comment: Does this answer only apply to path names starting with dir?

Comment: `dir` is a variable. It works for strings that do not start with the string `"dir"` as well.

Comment: Works good on this dataset but when I applied to my actual dataset it messed up, not sure why.

Comment: Do you have example data which will fail? I tried it with some additional paths and it looks good to me. If my answer is faulty, I'd rather delete it.

Comment: I believe it failed since your answer uses `data_list`  with two columns however my actual `data_list` consists of just one column. Answer works just fine otherwise :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on lists, not dataframe but you should get the idea. I guess you could do much better than that, e.g. by creating a directory tree as you go but I'll leave that up to you.

```
data_list = ['dir_1', 'dir_1/dir_2', 'dir_1/dir_2/dir_3', 'dir_1/dir_2/dir_4']

outList = []
for data1 in data_list:
    noSubdirExists = 0 if any(data2.startswith(data1) for data2 in data_list if data1!=data2) else 1
    outList.append((data1, noSubdirExists))

print(outList)
#Output: [('dir_1', 0), ('dir_1/dir_2', 0), ('dir_1/dir_2/dir_3', 1), ('dir_1/dir_2/dir_4', 1)]
```

Comment: Apologies , I just made a change in the question. Please take a look

Comment: @Luke doesn't matter too much for the solution